# Adding OpenGL library to Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-xe2

I was wanting to learn OpenGL using Delphi But never added an library to Delphi or even sure if this is what you need to do?  Anyone give some steps on how i would add openGL to delphi so i could call it in the uses section?

Comment: .. so OpenGL.pas of RTL is incomplete?

Comment: For 2D usages of OpenGL for UI and visualization purposes, check this out too: http://andorra.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a wrapper for the `OpenGL` dlls that declare the types and functions needed, and then you call those functions from your Delphi code. The VCL includes a somewhat limited (and generic) wrapper in `OpenGL.pas`, but there are better ones available.

One of the popular wrappers for Delphi is the Open Source [GLScene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glscene/), which includes demos and wrapper units. It also includes visual components that you drop on your form just like any other Delphi components. The link above is for the SourceForge project; the [GLScene web site](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/HomePage) has more information, including documentation and FAQs.

Comment: Sounds great checking it out now. Can't wait to try some OpenGL